# Custom sorting a DataGridViewColumn that contains a custom formatted date

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with a column that contains strings, formatted as "d.yy" (for example 2.13 is February 2013).

I would like to sort the DataGridView according to this column. I tried some various methods, including:

```
DataGridViewCellStyle qq = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
qq.Format = "m.yy";
dataGridView.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle = qq;

dataGridView.Sort(dataGridView.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

But it won't work, it sorted this way:

```
2.14
3.13
3.14
4.14
```

which is of course not I need.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: make another column that is yy.m and sort by that (can you sort by a hidden column?)

Comment: That seems to do the trick :) @Derek

Comment: OK.  I'll add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make another column that is yy.m and sort by that (can you sort by a hidden column?)